# Regexp: how to match a char without a escape char before it?

Tags: javascript, php, regex

Well, I have a string like `a:b:c:d:2\:3`.

So, I want match all colon char(`:`) for `PCRE` and `Javascript` Regexp.

The expected result is 4 colon: `[':', ':', ':', ':']`.

Example result split by `colon`:

**PHP**

```
Array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', '2:3')
```

**Javascript**

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', '2:3']
```

Example result match by `unescaped colon`:

**PHP**

```
Array(':', ':', ':', ':')
```

**Javascript**

```
[':', ':', ':', ':']
```

Thanks

Comment: and what have you tried so far? like, for example: *matching all colons that are preceded by a character that is not a backslash*

Comment: what is the benefit of obtaining such result `[':', ':', ':', ':']` ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest i think in the long run he will want to split the string at those colons

Comment: I want split. Sorry my bad english.

Comment: Yes, I want know the solution for PHP and JS. PHP uses PCRE.

Comment: For splitting at colons bordering to a word character use [`\b:`](https://regex101.com/r/HOc5KD/1)

Comment: @chris85 please post you answer. This work for me and I want give you up vote. Thanks!

Comment: And what if a string is like `a:b:c:d:2\\:3`? Won't there be 6 parts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a negative lookbehind to ensure the `:` is not preceded by a backslash.

```
(?<!\\):
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/IVtDSC/1

PHP:

```
preg_match_all('/(?<!\\\):/', 'a:b:c:d:2\\:3', $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Demo: https://eval.in/703687